# Is the instance of Method class in java is global unique

Tags: java, reflection, dynamic-proxy

In the whole jvm run life, is the Method class instance always unique?
for example,
I have a class which implements InvocationHandler.
In method invoke, which has a Method parameter.
I know all methods that i can handle, and I want to use different strategy to handle different method. So I build a strategy map like Map.
codes like:

```
@Override public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)  throws Throwable {
    Strategy strategy = strategyMap.get(method);
    Method realMethod = strategy.getCorrespondingMethod();
    return realMethod.invoke(this, args); 
}
```

The question is IF i use this strategy, the Method object MUST be global unique in the whole JVM running life. Otherwise, i cannot find the correct strategy.

So, Is the instance of Method class in java is global unique.

Question 2:
How about the efficient of Method:toGenericString(), i the use method object cannot accomplish this job, i think i can use method generic string.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You should see it in this way - *for a given class, the method instance is always unique*. The reason I added *for a given class* is because 2 same classes loaded using different class loaders will have different instances of the same method.

> How about the efficient of Method:toGenericString()

Well, *efficiency* is a *relative* concept. You have nothing against which `toGenericString()` can be compared. So, if `toGenericString()` does the job, go for it and forget about the efficiency :P

Comment: i agree the answer for q2. About q1, is that possible if one Class may be have different class loader???? cannot believe

Comment: Or A a, A b: a and b is two object Of class A. Is that possible a.class.getClassLoader() is different of b.class.getClassLoader()????

Comment: @CodeBoy - Yes. If you use 2 different class loaders to load 2 different classes then they will be different :)

Comment: thank you. And In what situation, there will be two class loader for one class.

Comment: @CodeBoy -  You can load a class twice using 2 different class loaders. Any situation which loads a class twice is usually *bad* and might lead to *side-effects* that cannot be usually forseen :P